# Json decode in php basics

Tags: php, json, decode

I'm trying to learn json in php. Here's my json result from a ElasticSearch query.

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "xenforo",
      "_type" : "post",
      "_id" : "1816069",
      "_score" : null,
      "sort" : [ 1365037907 ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

I assume that my php code will look something like this:

```
$myData = json_decode($result);

foreach($myData->hits as $var) {
   $post_id[] = $var->_id;
}
```

Been looking for the answer for hours, I sure do appreciate any help. Thank you.

Edit: Here is the answer:

```
foreach($myData->hits->hits as $var) {
   $post_id[] = $var->_id;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: See http://array.include-once.org/ on how to traverse data structures in PHP. Only [`->hits->hits` is meant to be iterated over](http://array.include-once.org/?foreach=1&assoc=&json=%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A++%22hits%22+%3A+%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A++++%22hits%22+%3A+%5B+%7B%0D%0A++++++%22_index%22+%3A+%22xenforo%22%2C%0D%0A++++++%22_type%22+%3A+%22post%22%2C%0D%0A++++++%22_id%22+%3A+%221816069%22%2C%0D%0A++++++%22_score%22+%3A+null%2C%0D%0A++++++%22sort%22+%3A+%5B+1365037907+%5D%0D%0A++++%7D+%5D%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: yes please explain the question, what are you trying to accomplish with the JSON object?

Comment: I would like to populate the $post_id array with the _id in the json output. So in this case $post_id[0] should equal 1816069.

Comment: your current JSON object only shows one `_id` parameter but it seems what you are asking involves getting multiple `_id` so can you modify your JSON so that it shows how the structure will look with multiple _ids?

Comment: ->hits->hits was the answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're one `->hits` short if you look at your JSON structure...

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [ {
            "_id" : "1816069",
```

---

```
$myData = json_decode($result);

foreach($myData->hits->hits as $hit) {
    $post_id[] = $hit->_id;
}
```